# An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

receiving the below error when attempting to add an entry to an access database on a visual studio asp site.

> An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code.
>   Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'EQEventNo= AND EQMemberRef=3'.

I am aware that i habve whitespace on my copnnection but i found a fix for that on this site and it seems to have worked, but now I am running into the new error

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

```
protected void RegisterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var getPass = txtPassword.Text;

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
    "Scripts","<script>alert('" + getPass + "');</script>");

    //Check if password entered if not message alert
    if (getPass == "")
    {

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Scripts", "<Script>alert('Password is required Please Enter');</script>");
        return; //Exit this event
    }

    //check if member is registered

    var getMem = DropDownList1.Text;
    var getEventNo = Request.QueryString["EQEventNo"];

    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source =C:\Users\David\Desktop\David McFall - web app 2\WebSite1\App_Data\OmaghEquestrianAssociation.accdb");



    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblEQApplicant WHERE EQEventNo=@EQEventNo AND EQMemberRef=@EQMemberRef", con);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EQEventNo", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = getEventNo;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EQMemberRef", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = getMem;
    try
    {

        con.Open();

    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Scripts",
            "<script>alert('Cannot connect to database');</script>");
        return; //Exit this event
    }

    int cnt = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    if (cnt > 0)
    {

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Scripts", "<script>alert('Member is already registered');</script>");
    }
    else
    {
        OleDbCommand cmdPass = new OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblEQMember WHERE EQMemberRef="
               + getMem + " AND Pssword=" + getPass + "'", con);
        int cntPass = (int)cmdPass.ExecuteScalar();

        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        string date = now.GetDateTimeFormats('d')[0];

        if (cntPass == 1)

        {
            string sqlcmd = "Insert into tblEQApplicant(EQEventNo, EQMemberRef, DateJoined) values (" + getEventNo + ", " + getMem + ", '" + date + "' )";
            OleDbCommand cmdReg = new OleDbCommand(sqlcmd, con);
            cmdReg.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
            //Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Scripts", "<script>alert('Member registered');</script>");

        }
        else
        {

            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Scripts", "<script>alert('Password Incorrect');</script>");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: EQEventNo is blank. Your error message tells you that.

Answer (score 0):

Use parameters instead of string concatenation to create your statement:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblEQApplicant WHERE EQEventNo=@EQEventNo AND EQMemberRef=@EQMemberRef", con);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@EQEventNo", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = getEventNo;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@EQEventNo", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = getMem;
```

Not only will it fix your error, it will also keep you safe from sql injection attacks.

Comment: I have tried this and it is still erroring out on the same line :                          int cnt = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Parameter @EQEventNo has no default value.

Comment: Did you change all your sql statements to work with parameters?

Comment: Please edit your question with the current code you are using.

Comment: Parameter EQEventNo has no default value.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Parameter EQEventNo has no default value.

Source Error:


Line 62:         }
Line 63: 
Line 64:         int cnt = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
Line 65: 
Line 66:         if (cnt > 0)

Comment: You should make sure there are values in your variables before even going to the database